# Relate two fields (on which is reliant on the other) to the same field in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

```
SELECT RECIPE.PRODUCTNUMBER, RECIPE.COMPONANTNUMBER, 
  RECIPE.COMPQUANTITY, RECIPE.COMPSEQNO, ITMMSTR.ITEMDESCRIPTION 
FROM RECIPETABLE RECIPE, ITEMMASTERTABLE ITMMSTR 
WHERE RECIPE.PRODUCTNUMBER=ITMMSTR.ITEMNUMBER
```

Comment: Essentially I am trying to bring the item description over from the item master table to the recipe table but I either run into the problem where if I say the product number is equal to the item number and I cant get any component descriptions OR I make the component number equal to the item number and the component descriptions are fine but I can't get the name of the product.

Comment: JAMIEC edit your question putting your comment above into it.  Also, put in sample data from both tables and a desired output so we can better respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to join to `ITEMMASTERTABLE` twice:

```
SELECT
    r.PRODUCTNUMBER, r.COMPONANTNUMBER, r.COMPQUANTITY, r.COMPSEQNO,
    p.ITEMDESCRIPTION as ProductDescription, i.ITEMDESCRIPTION as ComponentDescription
FROM RECIPETABLE r, ITEMMASTERTABLE p /*product*/, ITEMMASTERTABLE i /*item*/
WHERE
        r.PRODUCTNUMBER = p.PRODUCTNUMBER
    AND r.COMPONANTNUMBER = i.ITEMNUMBER
```

Of course you'll want to use ANSI join syntax instead:

```
SELECT
    r.PRODUCTNUMBER, r.COMPONANTNUMBER, r.COMPQUANTITY, r.COMPSEQNO,
    p.ITEMDESCRIPTION as ProductDescription, i.ITEMDESCRIPTION as ComponentDescription
FROM
    RECIPETABLE r
    INNER JOIN ITEMMASTERTABLE p /*product*/,
        ON r.PRODUCTNUMBER = p.PRODUCTNUMBER
    INNER JOIN ITEMMASTERTABLE i /*item*/
        ON r.COMPONANTNUMBER = i.ITEMNUMBER
```

Comment: Great! I will give it a try.